# Marklogic insert binary content taking long time

Tags: java, xquery, marklogic

I have a requirement of uploading image in Marklogic 6. My App ID deployed both in DEV and QA env, where image uploading is working fine in DEV but not in QA. In QA when trying to upload file, it's taking long time(5-10 mins),which usually takes few milli seconds and sometimes uploading gets failed and gives following exception:

```
ERROR] 17 Mar 2014 14:36:53,564 MarkLogicPersitenceManager - Broken pipe
com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.ServerConnectionException: Broken pipe
 [Session: user=user-name, cb=datastore [ContentSource: user=user-name, cb=datastore [provider: address=/172.11.11.11:1111, pool=1/64]]]
        at com.marklogic.xcc.impl.handlers.AbstractRequestController.runRequest(AbstractRequestController.java:110)
        at com.marklogic.xcc.impl.SessionImpl.insertContent(SessionImpl.java:194)
        at com.marklogic.xcc.impl.SessionImpl.insertContent(SessionImpl.java:222)
        at com.mhhhe.ecom.catalog.admin.persistence.ml.MarkLogicPersitenceManager.save(MarkLogicPersitenceManager.java:251)
        at com.mhhhe.ecom.catalog.admin.AdminResources.catalogSaveWithUriNew(
```

I have used following Java code to upload the file.

```
ContentCreateOptions contentOptions = new ContentCreateOptions();
contentOptions.setFormatBinary();
Content content = ContentFactory.newContent(uri, stream,contentOptions);
session.insertContent(content);
```

Even though both Dev and QA have almost same configuration, it is not working in QA. So this looks like a problem of Marklogic DB.

Could you please tell me what kind of configuration problem could be responsible for this?

Comment: How large is the image? Have you looked at the memory utilization in the QA and dev environments?

Comment: The images are around 600 to 700 Kb. Regarding memory, I haven't see anything alarming yet. But don't know much on this part. Could you please tell me which parameters you are asking about. I will list out them.

Comment: Between these two env, I can see one major difference in "Content Processing" features. In QA it's disabled. Could it be a reason for failure.

Comment: Disabling CPF shouldn't cause an upload failure. Maybe a firewall is interfering?

Comment: But apart from file uploading all other operation like executing X queries, search, fetch uploaded file are working fine

Comment: Ok let me check the firewall setup, I will back to you.

Comment: I got the following log entries during file upload.

Comment: Access Log : 172.16.80.139 - user-id [18/Mar/2014:09:17:24 -0400] "POST /invoke HTTP/1.1" 200 3324 - "Java/1.6.0_21 MarkXDBC/4.1-7"
172.16.80.139 - user-id [18/Mar/2014:09:17:25 -0400] "PUT /insert?uri=%2Fstore%2F1384%2Fimages%2FKoala.jpg&format=binary&locale=en_US&tzoffset=-14400&dbname=datastore HTTP/1.1" 500 308 - "Java/1.6.0_21 MarkXDBC/4.1-7"
172.16.80.139 - - [18/Mar/2014:09:17:25 -0400] "POST /eval HTTP/1.1" 401 209 - "Java/1.6.0_21 MarkXDBC/4.1-7"
172.16.80.139 - - [18/Mar/2014:09:17:29 -0400] "POST /invoke HTTP/1.1" 401 209 - "Java/1.6.0_21 MarkXDBC/4.1-7"

Comment: Error Log : 2014-03-18 09:17:25.006 Notice: datastore-xdbc: SVC-CANCELED: Canceled
2014-03-18 09:17:25.006 Notice: datastore-xdbc:  [1.0-ml]

Comment: That `SVC-CANCELED` seems odd. A timeout is normally `SVC-EXTIME` or `XDMP-EXTIME`. Usually `SVC-CANCELED` means that a request was explicitly canceled. Does the rest of the `Notice` message tell you which request was canceled?

Comment: Yes, this svc-canceled is appearing only during file uploading operation and if it is being compared with access log, there is no time gap between access log entry and error log entry.

Comment: You are getting a 500 error on the PUT /insert.  changing the log level to Fine or Finer might produce better diagnostics.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. After changing the log level, I have encountered one debug statement in Error log. Retrying XDBCConnectionTask::handleConnection 5 /insert because XDMP-DEADLOCK: Deadlock detected locking forest01 #2100171885223584270. I don't know what this numerical value is, but it's not the forest Id.  I have also changed the "maintain-directory-last-modified" tag for our marklogic DB to 'false', but still it's inconsistent. 90% time insertion is getting failed.

Comment: ......... and "2100171885223584270" is such a peculiar number.. not getting any clue.